# Alternative Stride integration with Jira and Confluence servers

Tags: jira, integration, confluence, stride

Atlassian Stride is aiming to forcefully replace HipChat product. However, its current version (1.8.18) lacks out of the box the integration with self-hosted Jira and Confluence as they were in HipChat (though having a way to integrate with Jira Cloud & Confluence Cloud). That is crucial to us and I believe for many other new Stride users who were moved from HipChat recently.

Atlassian support tells the official feature should appear *soon*, but doesn't name any specific dates:

- https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Stride-questions/Stride-Integrations/qaq-p/699522
- https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Stride-questions/Will-Stride-Cloud-integrate-with-JIRA-Server/qaq-p/636505
- https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/STRIDE-565 and more

We also checked Zapier, but haven't find anything related. Are there any alternative ways to connect servers of Jira and Confluence with Stride to feed the chat with updates, except writing our own app or waiting for Stride update?

Comment: I believe at the moment the only way is to use Stride API to make your own APP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stride has released a plugin for Jira Cloud that provides a nice integration between Jira Cloud and Stride which is now available and there is also a Jira Server plugin from Atlassian that provides a basic integration for Jira Server. For those looking to do more there is a 3rd party integration that provides deeper integration for both Server and Cloud.

**Jira Server:** https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1218852/

**Jira Cloud:** https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1217873/jira-cloud-for-stride.

**Jira Integration+ (paid):** https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1219096/integration-for-jira-and-stride

Answer (score 1):

You could use Microsoft Flow and it's amazing available template to connect it and set it up as you want. https://asia.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/

Comment: A nice tip, thanks. However, I was able to find only a direct email (Outlook) notification template there... Nothing related to Stride so far. Maybe I'm missing something?